# What are meaning of various labels to the issues in github?

Tags: github

[image]

According to my understanding:

- **Deferred** : Postponed
- **Design & Review** : For developers to design & review
- **Discuss** : To discuss with developers & users
- **Fix** : To be fixed by developers
- **Fixed**: Fixed by developers
- **Review** : To be reviewed by developers
- **UserResponseAwaited** : Waiting for user to respond
- **Verify** : To be verified by developers

Please correct me if I am wrong.

When to use **Communicate** - to communicate with users or developers?

***Note:*** Here **developers** means my own team of developers & **users** are those who are using our API.

Comment: I believe it's also possible to create new labels in GitHub, so you should not be bound by the defaults given to you.  If you can't find a reason to use `Communicate`, then don't use it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub labels ([introduced in July 2014](https://github.com/blog/1866-the-new-github-issues)) are custom for each project.
For example, [this one has a very different list](https://github.com/github/hub/labels).

So you define the semantic you want for your labels in your project when you create them (as shown in "[Creating and editing labels for issues and pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-editing-labels-for-issues-and-pull-requests/)").